# How do I stack accents in ancient Greek?

Tags: fonts, xetex, unicode, accents, greek

I want to type, in a XeLaTeX document, the following epigraph (https://epigraphy.packhum.org/text/145737?hs=50-58):

[image]

The problem is (for example) in the word inside the red rectangle, which is wrongly rendered as

[image]

by this MWE:

```
%to be compiled with XeLaTex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\newfontfamily\altfont{Segoe UI Symbol}%   Gentium Plus   KadmosU    Code2000    Segoe UI Symbol
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textaltfont}{\altfont}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek, Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX]{Gentium Plus}

\begin{document}

\begin{greek}
ἀσστοῖ[ς] καὶ χσέˉνοισι ξείνοισι φανὲˉς φίλος̣ [εἰμὶ \textaltfont{⏑} – ×]

[ὅ]ς πο[τ’] ἀρισστεύοˉν ἐν προμάχοις [ἔθανεν].
\end{greek}

\end{document}
```

Analyzing the source of the mentioned website you can see that the word is typed as "χσέˉνοισι". Therefore it seems that web tools are able to render the text correctly. How to do the same with XeLaTeX? Thanks in advance for any clue.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have to use *combining* characters rather than modifiers.

So the combination `ε̄́` can be input as

```
U+03B5 U+0304 U+0301
```

that is, epsilon, combining macron and combining acute (oxia). Similarly for `ε̄̀`, which is

```
U+03B5 U+0304 U+0300
```

because U+0300 is the combining grave.

```latex
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\setmainfont{Times New Roman}

\newfontfamily\altfont{Junicode}%Segoe UI Symbol}%   Gentium Plus   KadmosU    Code2000    Segoe UI Symbol
\DeclareTextFontCommand{\textaltfont}{\altfont}

\defaultfontfeatures{Scale=MatchLowercase}
\defaultfontfeatures[\rmfamily]{Ligatures=TeX,Scale=1}

\usepackage{polyglossia}
\setdefaultlanguage{english}
\setotherlanguage[variant=ancient]{greek}
\newfontfamily\greekfont[Script=Greek, Scale=MatchUppercase, Ligatures=TeX]{Gentium}

\begin{document}

\begin{greek}
ἀσστοῖ[ς] καὶ χσε̄́νοισι ξείνοισι φανε̄̀ς φίλος̣ [εἰμὶ \textaltfont{⏑} – ×]

[ὅ]ς πο[τ’] ἀρισστεύο̄ν ἐν προμάχοις [ἔθανεν].
\end{greek}

\end{document}
```

I had to change the fonts in order to get an output on my system.

[image]

Comment: Learning about combining characters was great, but in practice how do you create the combination? As far as I know Windows lacks a standard way to enter Unicode characters, the best tool I found is at https://www.fileformat.info/tool/unicodeinput/index.htm, but maybe there are better and simpler tools.

Comment: @mmj maybe your editor can help you. For instance, in emacs you can digit `C-x 8 RET` to start entering any unicode char (of course you need to have some font to see it; see  https://www.emacswiki.org/emacs/UnicodeFonts)

Comment: Still another approach, but cumbersome, is the `^^^^` notation: `ε^^^^0304^^^^0301`.